# push_back using raw pointers vs using smart pointers

Tags: c++, object, pointers, smart-pointers, push-back

I am having trouble understanding how to create new objects of a class and push it into a vector using smart pointers.

using raw pointers it would look something like this:

```
std::vector <Deck*> creat_cards; // vector with the objects
std::vector <Deck*> final_cards; //vector that will be copied into.

for (unsigned i=0; i <creat_cards.size(); i++) {

          final_cards.push_back(new Card(creat_cards[i]->getMonster(),creat_cards[i]->getCost(),creat_cards[i]->getType()));
      }
```

// this works

however I get an error when I try to do this:

```
std::vector <Deck*> creat_cards; // vector with the objects

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card*>> final_cards //vector that will be copied into.

for (unsigned i=0; i <creat_cards.size(); i++) {

          final_cards.push_back(new Card(creat_cards[i]->getMonster(),creat_cards[i]->getCost(),creat_cards[i]->getType()));
      }
```

Does push_back work with smart pointers?

Comment: `final_cards.push_back(std::make_shared<Card>(creat_cards[i]...));`

Comment: *Does push_back work with smart pointers?* -- It does.  The problem you're having with your code is that you are still holding onto raw pointer-type coding. while using smart pointers.  There shouldn't be a single `Deck*` or `Card*` in the second example if you are using smart pointers.

Comment: You likely meant `std::shared_ptr<Card>`, not `std::shared_ptr<Card*>`. The latter is similar to `Card**`, not `Card*`

Comment: but the second argument is of type Card* and it shouldn't change.
so I get the error no known conversion from `'Card *' to 'const
      std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>,`

Comment: [Take this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67e61e971f409ef5), add to it, and come back with the error you're saying occurs.  As you can see, that very simple case has no issues, and there is no need for `Card*` or `Deck*`.  As a matter of fact, that simple example should have been the first thing you should have written, so that you could familiarize yourself with the smart pointer syntax and usage.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the example I got it to work now :)

Comment: Why do you need to allocate your cards and decks on the heap, rather than storing them by value?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin because I want to make a deep copy of the objects and not the pointers

Comment: @konoha Your answer doesn't make much sense because copying a `shared_ptr` does a shallow copy (increments a reference counter). You get deep copies with values, not (smart) pointers. E.g `Card a{...}; Card deep_copy_of_a = a;`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin but when I allocate the objects with new from a shared ptr object and copy it to another shared_ptr vector with the method above the objects don't point to the same adress. And I can delete a object from one shared ptr vector with the object not being deleted in the other shard ptr vector. That is a deep copy am I right?

Comment: @konoha That's because you don't copy a `shared_ptr` but rather you create a new object and pass it to `shared_ptr` constructor. I recommend a vector of cards by value, e.g. `std::vector<Card> final_cards; ... final_cards.emplace_back(creat_cards[i]->getMonster(),creat_cards[i]->getCost(),creat_cards[i]->getType());` You may like to store `Deck` by value as well.